# Durandal: At what stage in lifecycle should router.isNavigating deactivate?

Tags: durandal

*sigh* It's becoming the "daily question" routine with me, sorry!

I have a nav.html that contains:

```
    <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
    </div>
```

Trouble is, it never deactivates!  The spinner always stays rotating, basically.

I've put in debugs in the viewmodels like in the Durandal html samples page:

```
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        //refresh: refresh,
        //sessions: sessions,
        title: 'My App Home Page',
        activate: function () {
            system.log('Lifecycle : activate : home');
        },
        binding: function () {
            system.log('Lifecycle : binding : home');
            return { cacheViews: false }; //cancels view caching for this module, allowing the triggering of the detached callback
        },
        bindingComplete: function () {
            system.log('Lifecycle : bindingComplete : home');
        },
        attached: function (view, parent) {
            system.log('Lifecycle : attached : home');
        },
        compositionComplete: function (view) {
            system.log('Lifecycle : compositionComplete : home');
        },
        detached: function (view) {
            system.log('Lifecycle : detached : home');
        }

        //viewAttached: viewAttached
    };
```

and in my Chrome dev console I have:

```
Lifecycle : bindingComplete : home system.js:73
Lifecycle : attached : home system.js:73
Lifecycle : compositionComplete : home system.js:73
```

...and I would have thought that "compositionComplete" would have triggered the end of "router.isNavigating", no?

The nav.html is composed in my shell.html file as so:

```
<header>
    <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
    <!-- /ko-->
</header>
```

Basically the spinner just stays there on the top right and never disappears.  I can navigate between my two pages and it just stays there, even though "compositionComplete" fires every time.

Entire shell.html file:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
        <!-- /ko-->
    </header>
      <div>
        <section id="content" class="main">
            <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
        </section>
      </div>
</div>
```

Edited shell.html file:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <span class="title">My test SPA</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
                    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: title"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Bilbo Baggins</a></p>
                <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
                    <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
      <div>
        <section id="content" class="main">
            <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
        </section>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be because the way you do the composition with the `router` in the `shell.html`.

In durandal 2.0 it should look like this:

```
<!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
```

Or if you want to keep it like the old way:

```
<!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        attached: router.attached,      
        compositionComplete: router.compositionComplete,     
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!--/ko-->
```

Also take into consideration that the css class `active` might not work as expected in the `div`for the loading gif. Instead you can use:

```
<div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="visible: router.isNavigating">
```

So you will hide the loader gif when it is not navigating.

Comment: I thought so too when I found the docs on the "new" way to do it. But I already edited that this morning (see above as I've edited initial post to show entire shell.html file).  No difference.

Comment: @CarlEdwards cool, thanks. By the way, are you using a child router?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Maybe the problem is that there's a problem composing the `nav` view in the shell. You could try to paste the code from `nav` into the shell directly and see what happens. I suspect the problem might be there..

Comment: Don't know what child routing is, sorry!  Have edited op to show edited shell.html file. No change.

Comment: @CarlEdwards could you change the binding to `router.isNavigating` by this one: `<div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="visible: router.isNavigating">`

Comment: code is now: `<div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { visible: router.isNavigating }">` and it's still there after everything has finished. Used code inspector to double check it has changed and emptied cache and hard reloaded. It seems as though router.isNavigating is always set to true?  Hmm. That's weird.  I just put in `<span data-bind="text: router.isNavigating"></span>` to check and it's showing "false" so that's thrown me!

Comment: @CarlEdwards Look carefully at the code. It should be `<div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="visible: router.isNavigating">` withouth `css`

Comment: Argh! Dammit. Sorry - that was just there from John Papa's SPA course code.  Yep can confirm that it works without the css bit in there.  Also works fine back in my nav.html composed into the shell.html file. I'll accept that as the answer now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CarlEdwards I'll update my question, just in case someone else is looking for the same question. No problem!